# Iterate over lists as values in dictionary to search for specific values, then add the key of that value to new lists, in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, if-statement, while-loop

I have a dictionary consisting of several keys with values that are lists, as such:

```
Dict = {keyA:[1, 3, 2], keyB:[2, 3, 4], keyC:[1,4,3]}
```

I want to create lists from this values, named from the values. The items in these lists are the keys that had these values in their corresponding lists.

```
list1 = [keyA, keyC]
list2 = [keyA, keyB]
list3 = [keyA, keyB, keyC]
```

So far I have managed to name the lists after the values that are existing in the dictionary value-lists:

```
Max_No = 12
N = 0
while N < Max_No: 
    N = N + 1
    locals()["list"+str(N)] = []
```

But when I try to expand this with while loops, so that I can iterate through the dictionary keys and values, things break down:

```
Max_No = 12
N = 0
while N < Max_No: 
    N = N + 1
    locals()["list"+str(N)] = []


N = 0
for key, value in Dict.items():
    while N < Max_No:
        N = N + 1
        if N in value:
            locals()["list"+str(N)].append(key)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

As the code is now, only the first key gets found and correctly placed. The rest of the lists turns up empty.

Comment: You now that the first thing helpers will do is copy'n'paste your code to see what happens. Please post real python data structures to ease that task.

Comment: One of the confusing things is that you switched from `.iteritems()` to just iterating over `Dict` in the latest edit. That would mean that you're using Python 2. In Python 3, you can get around the error you noticed by using `.items()` method instead.

Comment: I'm sorry @user2390182, but I cannot see how this is not real Python code? I have gone through the edited code and I can see that in one instance there is 4 spaces instead of tab, but they should be equal right? Could you please point me to what is wrong syntax-wise or otherwise? And then I will edit.

Comment: @rv.kvetch, using items() removed the error, but it didn't find the correct keys. I have edited to highlight this. Thanks!

Comment: My point being the `NameError`s this will raise. `keyA`, etc. one will either have to define oneself or surround by quotes to make it work which is tedious and would no doubt deter many from working on this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Max_No = 12
N = 0
while N < Max_No: 
    N = N + 1
    locals()["list"+str(N)] = []


Max = 13 
for key, value in Dict.items():
    for N in range(1,Max_No,1):
        if N in value:
            locals()["list"+str(N)].append(key)
```

This seems to work for me. Wanted to use a while loop, but this at least works.